# KQL: Unpacking array into columns

Tags: kql

I have the following records:

```
Message = User: Value1 \r\nComponent: Value2\r\nResult description: Value3\r\nName: Value4
Message = Event type: ValueA\r\nApplication: ValueB\r\nApplication\\Path: ValueC\r\nUser: ValueD
```

Using `| extend Message = split(Message, "\\r\\n")` I get the following results:

```
Message = ["User:Value1", "Component:Value2", "Result description:Value3", "Name:value4"]
Message = [Event type:ValueA", "Application:ValueB", "Path:ValueC","User: ValueD"]
```

I would like to use the "keys" here as column names and the "values" to populate them as such:

```
User  |Component| ResultDescription| Name | EventType | Application | Path
_________________________________________________________________________
Value1|Value2   | Value3           |Value4|           |             |
ValueD|         |                  |      | ValueA    | ValueB      | ValueC
```

I've tried using both `mv_expand` and `bag_unpack` but the most I've successfully been able to do looks like this:

```
Message
__________
["User:value1]
["Component:value2]
["ResultDescription:value3]
```

and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be inefficient, but you could try this:

1. use `extract_all()` to extract the key-value pairs from the input message
2. expand the pairs using `mv-apply`, and create a property bag out of them using `summarize make_bag()`
3. use `evaluate bag_unpack()` to unpack the property bag into columns

[Note: you may need to adjust the regular expression used in the example below to match the contents of your keys/values]

```
datatable(s:string)
[
    'Message = User: Value1 \r\nComponent: Value2\r\nResult description: Value3\r\nName: Value4',
    'Message = Event type: ValueA\r\nApplication: ValueB\r\nApplication\\Path: ValueC\r\nUser: ValueD',
]
| mv-apply e = extract_all(@"(\w+): (\w+)", dynamic([1,2]), s) on (
    project p = pack(tostring(e[0]), e[1])
    | summarize b = make_bag(p)
)
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

| s | Application | Component | description | Name | Path | type | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Message = User: Value1 Component: Value2 Result description: Value3 Name: Value4 |  | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |  |  | Value1 |
| Message = Event type: ValueA Application: ValueB Application\Path: ValueC User: ValueD | ValueB |  |  |  | ValueC | ValueA | ValueD |